# BeagleBoneBlack Cloud9 Not Working On Runtime SIOCADDRT: File exists Issue

Tags: cloud9-ide, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I recently picked up the BBB I have from some time ago (the Debian image is quite old) and have been following a book on my journey. I'm relatively new to embedded electronics.

Now, I'm having trouble with running Cloud9 on my BBB, and I can't find anyone with the same issue:

I can create files and restart the workspace, but whenever I click on "run", I get the following messages:

**SIOCADDRT: File exists**

Also, a small error message appears for a second, and it says the following:

**set option aggressive-resize -> on**

After that, all of my files are stopped for run time. I do want to note, that I can run all of the .js files in the terminal that I can open in Cloud9 and that works perfectly fine.

I'm really not sure as to what is causing this. When I check the web page itself, I get the following errors:

**Disregard terminal:  output203990**

**XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: [http://192.168.7.2:3000/vfs/1/9cmZHC5eYxOHaB7N/workspace/*/*/tab2?access_token=token](http://192.168.7.2:3000/vfs/1/9cmZHC5eYxOHaB7N/workspace/_/_/tab2?access_token=token)**
Line Number 1, Column 1:

It seems like the BBB is having trouble communicating between Cloud9 and its own self. I have tried 2 browsers--Firefox and Edge. If anyone else has encountered the same problem or could suggest a possible fix without me loading a new image onto the board (which would be the ultimate solution), that'd be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue was, but flashing a newer Debian image got rid of the problem.